# How to implement an async method for Design Time service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have an IMyService interface which has this method:

```
public Task<IList<int>> GetNumbers();
```

I have an implementation of `IMyService` which fetches the list of number from Server. Hence it is an async method.

My question is I need to do the same for a DesignTimeService. So I did:

```
public Task<IList<int>> GetNumbers()
{
    var lists = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        lists.Add(i);

    return lists;
}
```

But it won't compile. How can I return a `Task<IList<int>>`? If i am emulating getting the list of a number I generated locally?

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance for you to use `async`/`await`?

Comment: why do you need an ObservableColection?

Comment: out of curiosity, why intentionally slow down the design time implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just wrap the logic you need in a task and return that

```
public Task<IList<int>> GetNumbers()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<IList<int>>(() => 
    {
        var lists = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            lists.Add(i);

        return lists;
    });
}
```

Or use async/await

```
public async Task<IList<int>> GetNumbers() 
{
    var lists = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        lists.Add(i);

    return lists;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can just return `Task.FromResult(lists)`

Personally I'd try to go the `async` route though